# How to import cv2 in Pycharm in Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, pycharm

I built the OpenCV4 and installed the opecv4.0 using anaconda3 and its python3.7. My platform is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I can successfully use the OpenCV in terminal. But the PyCharm's project interpreter cannot find the opencv library, so I cannot use the import cv2 in my file.

I tried to rename the cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to cv2.so and then copy to the folder "/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site/package", but I still cannot see the opencv library in the PyCharm's project interpreter using the anaconda python interpreter and also cannot use the opencv library.

Because I built the OpenCV 4.0 by Cmake, I didn't install the anaconda's opencv library using conda command.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the path (where you installed it) in PyCharm's sources so it can be imported

Comment: Sorry, I am not smart enough to understand your words. What path should I add and how to do that?

Comment: I added the "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site/package"  to the "Add content root"  in the "file–>setting–>project:server–>project structure", but it didn't fix my problem.